# Should I use Int32[,] or System.Drawing.Point when all I want is the x,y coordinates?

Tags: c#, winforms, multidimensional-array, system.drawing

I am building an app that lets me control my Android devices from my PC. It's running great so now I want to start cleaning up my code for release. I'm trying to clean up solution references that I don't need so I took a look at the `using System.Drawing;` that I have for implementing the `Point` class. The thing is, I don't really need it if I switch to using a two-dimensional `Int32` array.

So I could have: `new Int32[,] {{200, 300}};` instead of `new Point(200, 300);` and get rid of the `System.Drawing` namespace altogether. The question is: does it really matter? Am I realistically introducing bloat in my app by keeping the `System.Drawing` namespace? Is `Int32[,]` meaningfully more lightweight?

Or, should I not use either and just keep track of the x,y coordinates in individual `Int32` variables?

**EDIT**: I got rid of the original idea I wrote: `Int32[200, 300]` and replaced it with `new Int32[,] {{200, 300}};` because as @Martin Mulder pointed out `Int32[200, 300]` "creates a two-dimensional array with 60000 integers, all of them are 0."

**EDIT2**: So I'm dumb. First of all I was trying to fancify too much by using the multi-dimensional array. Utter, overboard silliness. Secondly, I took the advice to use a struct and it all worked flawlessly, so thank you to the first four answers; every one of them was correct. But, after all that, I couldn't end up removing the System.Drawing reference because I was working on a WinForms app and the System.Drawing is being used all over in the designer of the app! I suppose I could further refactor it but I got the size down to 13KB so it's good enough. Thank you all!

Comment: Why don't you implement your own `Point` struct that doesn't rely on System.Drawing. I'm hoping that I misunderstand your usage of an `int` array to keep track of resolution...

Comment: Well, the point (heh) is that I don't need anything other than the two integers from the 'Point' class. Is 'struct' more lightweight than 'Int32[,]' or two `Int32`'s?

Comment: I would forget about the array idea. There's no context here for an array of any kind. A struct would essentially be two `int`s put together into one value, so it would be relativly equivalent to the two `int` idea.

Comment: Instead of an array or `Point`, you could just use a `Tuple<int, int>` to store it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing gets "embedded" in your application by just referencing a library. However, if the `Point` class really is all you need, you could just remove the reference and implement you own `Point` struct. That may be more intuitive to read instead of an `int` array.

`Int32[,]` is something different by the way. It's a two-dimensional array, not a pair of two int values. You'll be making things worse by using that.

You *could* use `Tuple<int, int>`, but I'd go for creating your own structure.

---

As some people have suggested implementations here. So just wrap your two integers, I'd just use this:

```
public class MyPoint
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}
```

Add all other features only if needed.

Comment: It's been years but I implemented a struct with x,y

Answer (score 3):

Just create your own:

```
public struct Point : IEquatable<Point>
{
  private int _x;
  private int _y;
  public int X
  {
    get { return _x; }
    set { _x = value; }
  }
  public int Y
  {
    get { return _y; }
    set { _y = value; }
  }
  public Point(int x, int y)
  {
    _x = x;
    _y = y;
  }
  public bool Equals(Point other)
  {
    return X == other.X && Y == other.Y;
  }
  public override bool Equals(object other)
  {
    return other is Point && Equals((Point)other);
  }
  public int GetHashCode()
  {
    return unchecked(X * 1021 + Y);
  }
}
```

Better yet, make it immutable (make the fields `readonly` and remove the setters), though if you'd depended on the mutability of the two options you consider in your question then that'll require more of a change to how you do things. But really, immutability is the way to go here.

Comment: Can you tell me why I would need to implement `IEquatable`? I really just want the two `Int32`'s.

Comment: You don't need to, but it's always a good idea to implement `IEquatable<T>` on a struct (and this would seem to be quite naturally a struct unless you've a reason otherwise) because the default equality is relatively expensive. Of course if you never compare two points, it'll never matter.

Comment: @MartinMulder strictly the `Equals()` inherited from `ValueType` would do the job correctly, but it goes through reflection which is more expensive than it needs to be.

Answer (score 2):

You are suggesting very ill advised:.

- `new Point(200, 300)` creates a new point with two integers: The X and Y property with values 200 and 300.
- `new Int32[200,300]` creates a two-dimensional array with 60000 integers, all of them are 0.
- (After your edit) `new Int32[,] {{200, 300}}` also creates a two-dimensional array, this time with 2 integers. To retrieve the first value (200), you can access it like this: `array[0,0]` and the second value (300) like `array[0,1]`. The second dimension is not required or needed or desired.

If you want to get rid of the reference to the library there are a few other suggestions:

1. `new Int32[] {200, 300}` creates an one-dimensional array of two integers with values 200 and 300. You can access them with `array[0]` and `array[1]`.
2. As Ron Beyer suggested, you could use `Tuple<int, int>`.
3. Create your own `Point`-struct (pointed out by Jon Hanna). It makes your applicatie a bit larger, but you prevent the reference and you prevent the library System.Drawing is loaded into memory.

If I wanted to remove that reference, I would go for the last option since it is more clear to what I am doing (a Point is more readable than an Int32-array or Tuple). Solution 2 and 3 are slightly faster that solution 1.

Comment: Its not really "impossible", theoretically (and ill-advised) you could use the upper bound of each dimension as the "point".

Comment: @Ron Beyer: Corrected! :)

Comment: I see your point(!). I wanted to be fancy with what I learned about multi-dimensional arrays but completely confused my thinking about a plain old boring `Int32[]`.

Answer (score 1):

As @Glorin Oakenfoot said, you should implement your own Point class.  Here's an example:

```
public class MyPoint // Give it a unique name to avoid collisions
{
   public int X { get; set; }
   public int Y { get; set; }
   public MyPoint() {} // Default constructor allows you to use object initialization.
   public MyPoint(int x, int y) { X = x, Y = y }
}
```

Comment: A class is a bit heavy-handed for this, no?

Comment: @Kristopher Not at all. It's very clear. That's the point. Code first for readability/maintainability, then optimize performance where you need to.

Comment: With that said, personally I would go with a struct, as a two-int struct is going to be 8 bytes, which seems more efficient than the object overhead, and in context is not likely to ever need to be unset/null. That's splitting hairs though, probably.

Comment: A struct would be fine.